# Calling a PHP class from AJAX responder-script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, class

I'm trying to reach a **PHP-File** via **AJAX**.

When I'm using a simple **PHP-File** like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, post-check=0');

$mode = $_POST['ajax_mode'];

switch ($mode) {
    case "test":
        if (isset($_POST['...'])) {
            $test = $_POST['...'];
            echo $test;
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

It's working fine. But if I try to use other classes, like a sql-class im getting a internal Server Error.

Here is my AJAX-Script:

```
function ajax(test, test1)
    {
        if (typeof test!== "undefined")
        {
            test_set = true;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!request) {
                alert("No Chance!");
                return false;
            } else {
                var url = ".../.../.../ajax_responder.php";
                request.open('POST', url, true);
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                request.send('ajax_mode=test' + '&test=' + test);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState === 4)
                    {
                        interpretRequest();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }

    function interpretRequest() {
        if (request.status != 200) {
            alert("Request-Error: " + request.statusText);
        } else {
            var content = request.responseText;
            var string_collection = content.split("_");
            alert(string_collection[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Here is the server-side script with the use of classes, with this version i get the Internal Server Errors

```
<?php

include '../../sql.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, post-check=0');
$mode = $_POST['ajax_mode'];
switch ($mode) {
    case "test":
        if (isset($_POST['...'])) {
            $ace = $_POST['...'];
            $sql = new sql_();
            echo $sql->execute();
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you show the server logs?

Comment: Can you share the server-side script that causes the errors (the version that uses other classes)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no Server Logs.

Comment: The error is in one of 2 lines, either:

$sql = new sql_();

or echo $sql->execute();

Comment out the "echo" line and echo something else - see if this works.

I am sure that it is something in the sql_() class causing the problem, either when the object is created or in the execute method - let's find out which one it is.

Comment: the Problem is coming in the Line "$sql = new sql_();" cause a normal echo show the right data. But how can i declare a new object of a class in a normal php script?

Comment: I understand that you can output the right data with an echo, there is something definitely wrong with the sql_() class. There are 2 methods called on this class in your script - the constructor (called in the "new" statement), and the "execute" method - one of them is making it crash. 

Do you know for sure that the script crashes as soon as the object is created? Try creating it but not calling any methods on it (by commenting it out)

Comment: I commented the methods out and everything went well

Comment: I used the sql script in other classes and no errors occure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer :D

the sql-class that i uncluded into my ajax responder calls another class, but the class is not known because i dont included the file of that class.

I included the new file and everything works just as fine :)

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion and possible answer - place your `include` after your headers:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, post-check=0');

include '../../sql.php';

$mode = $_POST['ajax_mode'];
switch ($mode) {
    case "test":
        if (isset($_POST['...'])) {
            $ace = $_POST['...'];
            $sql = new sql_();
            echo $sql->execute();
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

it could cause problems if you first include a file (which possibly produces error-messages) and then send your headers. as a rule of thumb, headers in `PHP` should be always set before any output occurs or could occur (unless you are using output-buffering, but that's another story).

if this doesn't help - have you tried to completely leave out your headers already?

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and your second, but it unfortunately does not work and now I'm frustrated

Comment: are you getting the same error? and can you please copy-paste an exact copy of the error-message?

Comment: Yes, im getting the same error and my error message is:
"The request was completed, but is not OK. Error: Internal Server Error, 500"

Comment: have you double-checked that the path to your `sql.php` is correct? what happens if you remove everything but the `include`-line and open the php page by itself (not via ajax) ?

Comment: when everything is commented (except the include and the sql object) and the .php file is opened on the server via browser then nothing happens. no error is shown, what tha heck?

Comment: so maybe you got the url to the php file wrong in your javascript?

Comment: That can't be true. If I only echo something in my .php-File it will be shown correct in the alert-Message. The Error has to be in the combination of ajax and php-classes